# Running docker container didn't recceive an ip address

Tags: docker

I want a docker container to automaticaly recceive an ip address from my own network. It seems to work if I do it with the default `bridge` network. But I don't want to use the default one because I have read it is a better practices to use a user-defined network.

At first I create my network with `--subnet=172.18.17.0/20` and `--gateway=172.18.17.1/20`

then I create a docker container with the following command:

```
docker container create --name myContainer alpine tail /dev/null
```

`tail /dev/null` is used here to keep the container running.

After that I connect to the network using `docker network connect`

due to the default bridge, which was created before, I need to disconnect from it using `docker network disconnect bridge myContainer`. I am arware of `--network` during container creation but because of situational reasons I am not allwed to use it. Maybe there Is a way to create the container without the default bridge network I think that would be a better solution but `--network none` blocks the possability to connect with new networks.

At the last step I start the container using

```
docker start myContainer
```

But now when I do an inspect on the container it has no IP Address in the NetworkSettings. `"IPAddress": "",`. I expected sth. like `172.18.17.2` or `172.18.17.3` here.

My current approach is that the Network and the container can't communicate. In a way I currently not understand.

Comment: `Maybe there Is a way to create the container without the default bridge network` <= yes, you attach it to a network you previously created with the `--network` option which would in the end bring you in the exact same situation you are trying to reproduce without using that option for a reason that does not seem to make any sense.

Comment: Why do you want this?  Without Docker involved, how do you assign IP addresses to individual processes on your host?  Can you use the `docker run -p` option to publish your service's port on a host IP address, and ignore the other Docker networking options?

Comment: As @Zeitounator said `--network` didn't work either.

@DavidMaze Processes wich running on the host machine use the host's IP. Publishing the container ports with `-p` isn't an option because It would be a huge configuration effort to have each container with own mapped ports. Also I want to Identify the containers by It's IP/Subnet.

Comment: After some tests I determined that the container is reachable even if it doesn't have a certain IP. Because of it is in a network and has a network IP.